# MongoDB cursor corrupted record crashing JVM

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm running some Java code which iterates through documents in a MongoDB collection using a cursor.

The process keeps throwing an exception:

```
BSONObj size: -286331154 (0xEEEEEEEE) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB) First element: EOO
```

Shortly after this the whole JVM seems to crash out.

This is happening with MongoDB 2.4, but it was happening with earlier versions too. 
The Mongo Java driver is: 2.7.2 d8951d7

Is this likely to be due to a corrupted record?
If so is it possible to repair the corruption, or prevent Java from dying?

Comment: When the whole JVM is crashing, you seem to have a much more serious problem. A corrupted record should not be able to cause this.

Comment: Does it crash on the same document? By "crashing out", do you mean an unhandled exception is occurring?

Comment: No the whole JVM dies. The exception coming back is handled so it doesn't die immediately, but shortly afterwards I get a JVM crash.

Comment: Try to see each document size from the mongo console (and also see if it is failing there). See this answer for example on how to do it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657690/document-size-in-mongodb. You can put a 16MB threshold in order not to print sizes for all documents.